Connection Issue with Connected App
I am trying to connect to salesforce from an external system and for that we are passing parameters such as org url, Username, password appended with security token and trying to hit from a node js script but it shows the following error  "INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out."
I have already checked the username, password, url, security token are correct I have tried regenerating new security token and adding it to password few times, and also checked if the user is locked, above parameters are correct. What should we look for to resolve this ?
[![PFA][1]][1]

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you tried another connection tool like curl or Postman?

This flow is turned off by default in newer orgs because it's outdated and insecure. Use one of the other flows: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5

@identigral - As this is a sandbox I don't have SSO Enabled for this org. Do I need to enable it to access Using connected app ?
